# How to use Zend Feed Reader in Laravel

Tags: php, zend-framework, laravel-4

my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "zendframework/zend-feed": "2.3.*@dev"
}
```

my controller

```
use Zend\Feed\Reader\Reader as feed;

class CronController extends \BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
    feed::import('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds');
}
}
```

im getting error

Class 'Zend\Http\Client' not found

any idea how to use zend feed reader in Laravel? thanks

Comment: Did you run the "composer.phar dump-autoload" command?

Answer (score 0):

Zend's modules are not **platform-agnostic**.

I.e, you'll need to write a service provider to use them in Laravel and may face more compatibility issues in the future.

Hence, i suggest you look into a Feed Reader package for Laravel itself.

Example: https://github.com/awjudd/l4-feed-reader